# How to avoid confirm window after saved data Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dialog

When I add the card to the in box. Then it is possible to double click on the card, and dialog pop up.
In the dialog I have Tow buttons (Save) and (Cancel). When I press Cancel buttons a confirm window pop-ups.

I want when I press the Save button, and after there press the Cancel Button this confirm window should not pop-up. But if I didn't save the data, and press the cancel button the confirm window should pop-up. I tried by my self to fix it with boolean and if sentence, but don't succeed.

I have a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/62QY8/74/)

```
 // Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
    $('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
        $currentTarget = $(e.target);

        $('#modalDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            position: 'center',
            buttons: {
                Save: function () { //submit

                    save(true);

                },
                Cancel: function () { //cancel

                        cancel(true);

                }

            }
        });

    });

    function save() {

            var val = $("#customTextBox").val();
            $currentTarget.find(".ctb").val(val);
            $currentTarget.find(".date").val($("#datepicker").val());           

        }

    function cancel() {

            $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 300,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                buttons: {
                    YES: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                        $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use boolean

```
// Double click to open Modal Dialog Window
$('#userAddedCard').dblclick(function (e) {
    $currentTarget = $(e.target);

    $('#modalDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        height: 600,
        width: 500,
        position: 'center',
        buttons: {
            Save: function () { //submit

                save(true);

            },
            Cancel: function () { //cancel

                    cancel(true);

            }

        }
    });

});
 var boolean = false;
function save() {

        var val = $("#customTextBox").val();
        $currentTarget.find(".ctb").val(val);
        $currentTarget.find(".date").val($("#datepicker").val());         
        boolean = true;  

    }

function cancel() {

    if(!boolean){
        $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            buttons: {
                YES: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $('#modalDialog').dialog("close");
                },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

    }
    else{
        $('#dialog-confirm').hide();
    }
}
```

when you click on cancel it display pup-up and when you click it on after save click on save button its hide.

Comment: I'm sorry but it don't seems to work. Here is the JSFiddel, I have implement the code: http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/62QY8/75/

Comment: $('#dialog-confirm').hide(); for to know that you hide you dialog. not for conform dialog. you can also put that you close dialog event which you add on right-top .. "X" like that

Comment: But I want to be able to close the window after saved data, when pressed the cancel button. Now I'm not, with that part of code.